# Mysql IN clause vs range for auto increment ID

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a MYSQL table with ~50 million rows (and expected to grow). Now I need to iterate over entire table. I am trying to to the iteration in chunks, i.e., fetch N rows, process, fetch another N rows

The table has auto-increment integer ID as primary key. This would make it easier to iterate. My question is: which statement will be faster (where is a sort of loop counter):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID IN (i, i+1, ..., i+N)
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID >= i AND ID < i + N
```

The first uses `IN` clause, which does a lookup over primary key, which I would think to be pretty fast. The second has a less than+greater than condition which, for a non-indexed column will be pretty slow. But since I am doing it on primary key, I am not sure about the performance.

Which of these should give better performance, for let's say `N = 1000`?

Comment: Why don't you try it out your self and analyse the results?

Comment: Doing that as well, but wondering if someone can put some theoretical light on it...

Comment: The second version.  You really ought to spend a little time learning about [B-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree) data structures (which is how MySQL indexes are implemented): it should be fairly obvious that locating a range from such a structure is O(log n), whereas locating m specific nodes—whilst not *hard*—is still O(m\*log n).

Answer (score 2):

Use this one:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID >= $i AND ID < $i + $N
```

The "range scan" is quite happy to find the first row (at $i), then get the Next, Next, ...  It is quite efficient.

This does assume, however, that the IDs are dense.  If you have deleted a lot of rows, you may not be working with $N rows each time.  (Yes, you could argue that this does not matter much.)

$N = 1000 -- This is a reasonable number -- You are not taking "too long", you are not "blocking" too many rows.  Etc.

For other techniques (such as when it is not dense), see [my blog on deleting in chunks](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig).

Comment: Of course, to always have chunks of a certain size irrespective of density one could do `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ID >= $i LIMIT 1000`, using the maximum `ID` from the previous chunk as the next value of `$i`.